# Too many open files in network client - what's anon_inode?

Tags: python, network-programming

I have a client process that does RPC (via ømq) to a server process. I left the client running in the debugger all weekend.

This morning, I was greeted with a ton of "Too many open files" errors from the client. Naturally, the logger did not record the exception stack trace, so I'm trying to locate where the error originated. I assumed that somewhere I'm not properly closing a socket. However, the output of lsof reports a bunch of these (the pid is 2369):

```
seth@titan ~ $ lsof | grep 2369
...
python     2369  2427                seth  947u     0000               0,10         0       7715 anon_inode
python     2369  2427                seth  948u     0000               0,10         0       7715 anon_inode
python     2369  2427                seth  949u     0000               0,10         0       7715 anon_inode
python     2369  2427                seth  950u     0000               0,10         0       7715 anon_inode
...
```

I was expecting to see a bunch of sockets in `TIME_WAIT` or something.

What are the `anon_inodes`? Do they have anything to do with networking, or am I barking up the wrong tree?

This is python3.4.3 on mint 17.3 (3.19.0-33-generic #38~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP).

Comment: might just be shared memory segments